# How to link news feed heading to news posted page ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below i attached the news feed script, i can gets feeds from that page. But i can not link the news heading to news posted page... please help me to do this.

```
var html = '';
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/3.0?tags=msit', function (data) {
     $(data).find("item").each(function () {
     var el = $(this);
     html +='<li>';
     html += '<h3>'+ el.find('title').text()+ '</h3>';
     html += '<img src='+ el.find('image').text()+'>'+'</br>';
     html += '' + el.find("description").text()+'</span>';
     html +='</li>';
  });
  $("#get_feeds").html(html);
});
```

Comment: You mean that you want to add a link pointing to the original URL of the article (the <link> tag in the feed)?

Comment: yes... eg : i want to read more about the article, click on the heading or title, go to that page.

Comment: Come on ... how do majority of links work on websites? Really seems like a lack of research went into this ... or question/problem mentioned isn't specific enough

Answer (score 0):

To add a link in the heading that opens the original article (contained in the `<link>` tag in the data feed) you can add an anchor tag (`<a>`) around the title text.

The anchor tag should have a `href` attribute pointing to the URL of the original article.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/3.0?tags=msit', function (data) {
            var html = '';
            $(data).find("item").each(function () {
                var el = $(this);
                html +='<li>';
                html += '<h3><a href="' + el.find('link').text() + '">' + el.find('title').text() + '</a></h3>';
                html += '<img src="' + el.find('image').text()+'">' + '</br>';
                html += '' + el.find("description").text() + '</span>';
                html +='</li>';
            });
            $("#get_feeds").html(html);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="get_feeds"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Updated with full example*

Comment: Thanks again... it really helped me. :)